# SQL DB Design of table for ASP.Net Gaming site

Tags: sql-server, database-design, asp.net-4.5

I am making a game information site using ASP.NET and SQL and need a bit of help deciding the best way to design the table that will hold the release dates. I was thinking a two column design (`ExactDate`, `RoughDate`) with each column being nullable, but it just did not seem right. The table will need to be able to hold the following date formats and I would like to order by the closest date to the current date (so the games coming out sooner are listed first):

```
DD-MM-YYYY
(Q1/Q2/Q3/Q4)-YYYY
(Early/Mid/Late)-YYYY
(Spring/Summer/Fall/Winter)-YYYY
TBA
```

Any ideas on how best to deal with the different dates?

Comment: Why did 2 columns not seem right? Having "display date/text" and "sort date" seems entirely valid and lets you sidestep issues such as should Q1-2013 appear before or after Early-2013, letting you get on with delivery.

Comment: @chrisb The original idea of two colums would be one that had normal dates and the other that had the text based dates I was not thinking about a Display date and a sort date two column setup. I think that would work well actualy.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per my comment above, I think its probably worth considering whether you need anything more than a 2 column display date/sort date system - I'd be inclined to go with this simple option until its adding too much friction, at which point you could reconsider...

As far as a less-simple model goes then; if release dates (and their relative ordering) was important enough that you wanted to ensure that Early-2013 appeared before 21/02/2013 (or vice versa) then you could establish a "release dates" table.

```
DisplayText | Type | Start      | End
01/01/2013  | 1    | 2013-01-01 | 2013-01-01
Q1-2013     | 2    | 2013-01-01 | 2013-03-31
Early-2013  | 3    | 2013-01-01 | 2013-06-30
```

This would get preloaded with every combination for the next 20 years or whatever (which is still only a few thousand rows..) and you'd just treat it as a FK and use the usual join syntax to make use of it.  Ordering can be done through the Start/End columns, and you can restrict searches to those ranges too (perhaps for, only games likely to be released in next 6 weeks or whatever)

As I say, I really wouldn't advise going this route straight away as its main benefit would be ease of integration with a ui designer and consistency (as there is no human decision making aside from selecting an option) so until you're done building your site out I'd absolutely not bother :)

Answer (score 0):

I’d go with a two column design (DisplayText nvarchar, RelaseDate date)

ReleaseDate would be a computed column that would calculate it’s date based on data stored in DisplayText column.  Just create UDF that would calculate date based on what is stored in DisplayText column and you should be good. This UDF will be a bit complex but not too much.

If you want to make it a bit less performance intensive then create ReleaseDate as non-computed column but use trigger to update its value every time value in DisplayText is inserted or updated.